# multithread : new form close too fast

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms, progress-bar, marquee

I want to show a new form with a progress bar marquee. This form should be on an other thread, since the action that is called is too big and the UI doesn't update the progress bar if it's on the same thread.

I call a new thread, create my form, but as soon as it appears, the form close...

Here is my code from my main :

```
    frmProgress f = new frmProgress();
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate() { f.Show(); }));
    t.Start();
    documentManager.Compile(); //This is my big action
    t.Abort();
```

Here is the code of form :

```
    public frmProgress()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

I would like to know what I did wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the `BackgroundWorker` class and it's `ReportProgress` method?

Comment: Yeah, but I thought it would be more simple to use "new Thread()" and to abort when I'm done...

Comment: @LolCat No, it's much less simple actually.

Comment: @LolCat It may be wortwhile to create a simple test application and use the examples referenced in Servy's answer.  Once I became familiar with BackgroundWorker, it made my life a lot easier many times.

Comment: I'll try with the BackgroundWorker then. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems:

1. You're showing a form in a non-UI thread.  This will only cause problems; it needs to be in the UI thread.
2. You're performing a long running task in the UI thread; this is blocking UI updates.

You need to be showing the forum in the UI thread, and running the long running task in a background thread.

A great tool for the job here is to use a `BackgroundWorker`.  It will do much of the work for you to ensure the proper code is running in the UI/non-UI threads as it should be.  Create a new `BackgroundWorker` and put the long running task in the `DoWork` event.  Make any simple UI updates that you need to (showing the form) before you start the BGW, and do any cleanup in the `Completed` event (which will run in the UI).  The [MSDN page on BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) has some [nice examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Another advantage of using a `BackgroundWorker` is that you can easily report progress (if you have a good way of knowing your % complete) rather than just having a marquee bar.  Just add a handler to the `ProgressReported` event handler to update the progress bar, and call the `ReportProgress` method periodically when doing work.  See the linked examples for exact code snippets.